# Cant access phpMyAdmin after changing the privileges username and password (ERROR1405)

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I can't seem to get back into phpMyAdmin after changing the privileges, I keep getting the following error:

> ERROR 1405
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1045 - Access denied for user 'â€˜rootâ€™'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I am using XAMPP on a mac. Not sure on how to go about fixing this, any ideas?

Comment: In `config.inc.php` what is your auth_type -- config, cookie, or http? First thing I suggest is to clear your browser cookies related to phpMyAdmin (they start with "pma") and try again, or try a new browser. Try logging in at the command line with your username and password `mysql -u root -p` or use your username instead of root.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php` and edit the file. The default file (without any password being set) looks like this.

```
<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

- If you remember the password then you can directly enter that in the password field.
- if you don't remember setting any password and it still shows some value then change it to '' (empty string).
- If this doesn't work then open the command line interface as a administrator and type `sc delete mysql`. This would delete the previous settings which you did in the mysql.
- Now restart now xammp server and open phpMyAdmin.